# What does mutability of val objects mean in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

If val and var stands for immutability and mutability . The what does
val newList = mutableListOf(1,2,3) mean ?

Comment: The reference (``newList``) is immutable - it will only ever point to that ``List`` object you're creating. But what goes on inside that object is the object's business, and if it has mutable state, assigning it to a ``val`` can't change that. It might help to think of ``val`` as *read-only* - you can ``get`` it, but you can't ``set`` it

Answer (score 1):

Objects are *reference values*. So you have two things: newList is a val containing a reference to a mutable list. NewList cannot be changed to a reference to a different object.

The object that was created by “mutableListOf(1,2,3)” is stored somewhere in memory, and you can modify it. If you say remove the 3 and add a 4 you have the same object but with different contents. The reference stored in newList is unchanged and cannot be changed. It now references the same object, which now has items 1,2 and 4.